# spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1 plugin builds ok in grails 3.0.8 but not 3.1.0.RC1

Tags: grails, plugins, spring-security

As far as I can tell, the spring-security-core:3.0.0.M1 plugin doesn't build in 3.1.0.RC1.

The 3.1.0.RC1 stack trace states

```
Unable to start embedded Tomcat 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception
...        
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':main:bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

If I include the 3.2.9 jars as suggested here [Grails 3.1.0_M2 - Spring-Security-Core 3.0.0.M1 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828221/grails-3-1-0-m2-spring-security-core-3-0-0-m1-error) the 3.1.0.RC1 build gives a different stack trace:

```
ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Factory method 'securityProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties]: Factory method 'securityProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/issues/401

and btw: spring-security-core-3.0.0 has been released.

Comment: Install 3.0.0 from https://bintray.com/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/view - the initial M1 release was published with a different name but going forward this repo is the one to use.

Comment: Thanks that works after I updated from staticRules to Requestmaps :)

Answer (score -1):

The workaround described above works in 3.1.0.RC1 with the spring-security-core:3.0.0 plugin. Requestmaps are required instead of a map of staticRules.

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment. And it's incorrect - requestmaps are _not_ required, you just need to read the docs about the new format for defining `staticRules`